# cElementTree.ParseError: multiple elements on top level

Tags: python, xml-parsing, xsd

I have this python code that accepts as input an XML file. When I run the execution, I get the error indicated in the title of the question:

```
for event,element in cElementTree.iterparse(io, events = ( b'start',b'end')):
    if event == b'start':
        self.TreeBuilder.start(element.tag, element.attrib)
```

**error**:

```
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymzml/run.py", line 370, in
> __init__
>     self.TreeBuilder.start(element.tag, element.attrib) 
      cElementTree.ParseError: multiple elements on top level
```

help me to solve this problem! thank you.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and say the problem is probably that you have multiple elements on the top level.

Comment: Did you have this problem with a normal `mzML` file? If so, you could file a bug report/fix at [pymzML on github](https://github.com/pymzml/pymzML) or provide [us](http://pymzml.github.io/intro.html#contact-information) an example file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm guessing correctly, it appears you are parsing an XML fragment with multiple root nodes while TreeBuilder is expecting a rooted document.

Try wrapping your parsing with calls to create a tree with a single root node. In other words:

```
self.TreeBuilder.start("root", {})
[...]
for event,element in cElementTree.iterparse(io, events = ( b'start',b'end')):
    if event == b'start':
        self.TreeBuilder.start(element.tag, element.attrib)
[...]
self.TreeBuilder.end("root")
```

Just remember that the resulting DOM has this extra element at the top and modify your processing to take that into account.

Comment: You're welcome. If that took care of your problem, accepting my answer is appreciated.